Unable to Remove Default Action Bar Behavior Before App Initialization on Android Using Custom Activity in Qt 6.7
I am developing a Qt-based Android application and attempting to remove the default action bar that briefly appears with the activity name before the app fully loads. Despite following Qt and Android documentation, the default behavior persists, and no solution seems to work effectively.
Steps to I tried:
I created a custom activity by extending QtActivity to override the onCreate method.
package com.example.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity;

public class MyCustomActivity extends QtActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Ensure the Action Bar is removed
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

I also Attemped to modify the theme programmatically in the custom activity or through
styles.xml.
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

I applied the custom activity in the AndroidManifest.xml.
The application should launch without displaying the default action bar at any point, ensuring a seamless, action-bar-free experience.
Actual behavior:
The action bar briefly appears before the custom activity or theme settings take effect, causing an unintended visual disruption see attached video.
Attempts to use Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar and similar themes in styles.xml did not fully resolve the issue.
The default action bar behavior appears to be tightly coupled with Qt's initialization process, and documentation suggests QtActivity does not fully support AppCompat.
Tested on multiple Android devices running different OS versions, with consistent results.
Environment:

Qt version: 6.7
Android NDK/SDK version:NDK 16.0,SDK 25
Application theme: Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

How to prevent the action bar from appearing entirely before the app fully loads?
